# minibuffer resizes while typing into minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer

There is an annoying quirk of my minibuffer.  Can you help me trace its origin?

Typing into the minibuffer causes it to instantaneously resize to 2 or 3 lines in height, and then back to 1 line.  It happens far too quickly to take a screenshot.  Best guess is it is a side effect of minibuffer autocompletion.

Do minor modes in other buffers, like Yas and AC, apply to the minibuffer?  I thought not.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `resize-mini-windows` to `nil`:

```el
(setq resize-mini-windows nil)
```

You can also customize option `max-mini-window-height`, to let it resize but limit how much it grows.

See the Emacs manual, node [Minibuffer Edit](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-Edit.html).